# How to add a word in the list of Alphabetical order in python programming language without repeating letters from the alphabet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add a word in the list of Alphabetical order in python programming language without repeating letters from the alphabet?

Here's my code:

```
key=input("Enter key:")
key=key.replace(" ", "")
key=key.upper()
    
result=list()
for c in key: #storing key
    if c not in result:
        result.append(c)
flag=0
for i in range(65,91):
    result.append(chr(i))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take input from user

```
key=input("Enter key:")
key=key.replace(" ", "")   #to remove space if any between characters
key=key.upper()            #to convert to upper case
```

Take set of key to remove duplicates from key:

```
key=set(key)
```

Finally, sorted the set with sorted, it will return a list:

```
result=sorted(key)
```

Comment: thank you very much, i already got it :)